# Closing an xml file after reading it with Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, file-access

I'm making a script for publishing web applications with PowerShell.

Since I'm early in development I edit the script and the xml file alternately. Right now, the script is quite small and simple:

```
$settings = [xml](Get-Content c:\PublishData.xml)
$whereToProjectsAreLocally = $settings.publishing.globals.localprojectdir
```

But I do have a problem. Once I launch the script and check that everything works as planned I see that editing the xml file (via Notepad++) is impossible. I receive an error message that the save failed and I should check if the file is used by another application.

No other applications apart from Notepad++ and the Powershell ISE aren't using the file.

Closing the ISE does not solve the problem (closing the ISE everytime I launch the script isn't my dream solution either).

Closing the Notepad++ doesn't solve the problem either (although the newest version remembers changes even if I don't save them, but that's not the solution either).

I suppose there is something like an XmlReader in the background that I haven't closed. My question is: how do I close it after reading the content from the xml file?

**EDIT**: Same script works fine if the xml is not stored on C:\ but in a lower directory. How can I make it work in the root directory C:\ ?

Comment: This doesn't happen for me on my powershell v4, there's a good chance it's being caused by something else.

Comment: Use Sysinternals' [Handle](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) to check which process is locking the XML file.

Comment: ./Handle.exe C:\PublishData.xml said "No matching handles found."

Comment: My crystal ball tells me that you launch the PowerShell ISE with elevated privileges (Run as Administrator) but not Notepad++

Comment: @helb, you are right. That was the case. Shame on me...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$xmlFile = 'c:\PublishData.xml'
$rawXML = Get-Content $xmlFile -Raw
$settings = [XML]$rawXML
```

Edit: Was just thinking, this may be another option:

```
$settings = [xml]([System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines($xmlFile))
```